# average of specific rows in a file and output in tab-delimited file

Tags: awk, columns, numeric-data

I have 6 rows in files. I need to find average only of specific rows in a file and the others should be left as they are. The average should be calculated for A1 and A2, B1 and B2, other lines should stay as they are. There are `n` columns in total.

Input:

```
A1  1   1   2
A2  5   6   1   
A3  1   1   1   
B1  10  12  12
B2  10  12  10
B3  100 200 300
```

Output:

```
A1A2  3    3.5   1.5     
A3    1    1     1
B1B2  10   12    11    
B3    100  200   300
```

The script is following. However, the output is not tab-delimited. How can I do it tab-delimited?

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 ~ /^[AB]1$/ { for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) val[$1,i]=$i; next }
$1 ~ /^[AB]2$/ { p=$1; sub(2,1,p); $1=p $1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=($i + val[p,i])/2 }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
A1A2  3    3.5  1.5
A3    1    1    1
B1B2  10   12   11
B3    100  200  300
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `BEGIN { OFS="\t" }` at the start of the awk script and change `{ print }` to `{print $1, $2, $3, $4}`. That will change the output field separator of awk to tab from the default of space.

## EDIT:

For n columns, you can use `{$1 = $1; print}` instead of `{print}`. I am not sure how this works internally, but it works when I test it.

Comment: that only works if you print fileds explicitly by numbers. Otherwise (just with { print } ) awk seem to not insert delimiters. I guess it treats print as print $0, so no delims requried

Comment: @Tagwint Yes, i had not noticed that. Edited to fix that.

Comment: @munircontractor There are n columns in the file, not only four.

Comment: @Anni Sorry...see my edit now.

Comment: @munircontractor It does not seem to work. I tried to check if the output is tab delimited by awk -F "\t" '{print $2}' output.txt and it gave nothing. awk -F " " '{print $2}' output.txt gives the second column. But I still need it to be tab-delimited

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure how the `$1 = $1; print` works internally, but it worked on a simple test I did. Sorry if it did not work for you. Other than this, I would try using `printf` to implement a tab delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

One more awk can do the thing

```
awk -f tst.awk file | column -t | awk -v OFS='\t' '{ print $1,$2,$3,$4 }'
```

Comment: As I stated in my initial message: There are n columns in total, not four.